# Get # character in firefox on mac using wireless UK keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Firefox on my Mac Pro and on my Macbook and need to use the `#` sign for C# programming and hashtags in Twitter.

I know that <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> should give me `#` and this works without problem on my macbook. However on the Mac Pro I have a UK apple wireless keyboard (aluminium version), which when I use <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> it switches to the third tab.

On my mac book I do this with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, however on the Mac Pro it switches with both <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

Does anyone else have this same problem, and is there a setting which changes this behaviour or another key combo which does this?

Answer (score 1):

Alt-Gr (right hand Alt key) + 3/£ key = #

That's what I use.

Comment: Thanks, I get the same result. It is odd, because it works fine in other applications, it is just firefox that doesn't. I'm using ff3.0, so may try upgrade to 3.5. Are you using UK wireless keyboard too?

Comment: I'm just using the wired keyboard and the inbuilt keyboard.

Comment: (Nitpicking: though a Mac keyboard may show "Alt" just in case you're using a Mac to control a Windows or Linux machine, in Mac OS it's "Option", not "Alt"...)